# Git cherry-pick will case merge conflict

Tags: git, merge

Currently I got two branches:

master

beta_001

beta_001 is checked out from master sometimes ago.
To make beta_001 update to date to master, commits pushed in master will also be cherry-picked to beta_001. All things worked fine until the day beta_001 was merged back to master.

a lot of `both modified` conflict apperenced like this:

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
+     <permission
+         android:name="com.xxx.permission.REDIRECT_MESSAGE"
+         android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
+     <permission
++=======
 +    <permission
 +        android:name="com.xxx.permission.REDIRECT_MESSAGE"
 +        android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
 +    <permission
++>>>>>>> origen/beta_001
```

or this

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++=======
+ 
+     <string name="xxx">xxxx</string>
++>>>>>>> origen/beta_001
```

I guess this is the case one change with difference commit ids due to cherry-pick, so how to prevent this?

Comment: is your branch beta_001 local or shared?

Comment: @nak It's shared.

Comment: What is the difference between both the branches? I mean what are they use for?

Comment: @beta_001 is checked out from master, some new features was write in this branch, and if master has new commits, we cherry-pick it to beta_001.

Answer (score 0):

Cherry Pick will always create a new id for every commit picked in the new branch and this will definitely show conflicts when we try merging to the branch the commits were cherry picked from.

If you want to follow your current branching model, you should **merge master into beta_001** branch to get all the commit from the master with the same commit id. This will add a merge commit but avoid the conflicts you mentioned.

Alternatively, you can change your branching model to GitFlow for better branch management. 
https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Comment: What's the difference? merge master into beta_001 still got conflicts...May be I misunderstand? Could you explan more?

Comment: **Do not cherry-pick from master**. Just merge master to beta_001. If there are conflicts (where someone else has changed the same line you changed in beta_001) then it will show. It will not show the kind of conflicts you mentioned in the questions